# Spawn EC2 instance via Python

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ec2-ami

Can someone help me to understand the basics of spawning EC2 instances and deploying AMIs and how to configure them properly?

***Current situation***:
In my company we have 1 server and a few clients which run calculations and return the results when they are done. The system is written in Python but sometimes we run out of machine power so I am considering to support the clients with additional EC2 clients - on demand. The clients connect to the server via an internal IP which is set in a config file.

**Question**:
Am I assuming right that I just create an AMI where our Python client sits in autostart and once its started it connects to the public IP and picks up new tasks? Is that the entire magic or do I miss some really great features in this concept?

**Question II**
While spawning a new instance, can I start such instance with updated configuration or meta information or do I have to update my AMI before all the time I make a small change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to stick with just plain spawning EC2 instances, here are the answers to your questions:

Question I - This is one of the valid approaches and yes, if your Python client will be configured properly, it will 'just work'.

Question II - Yes, you can achieve that, which is very well explained here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html. There's also another way of having your configuration stored somewhere else, and just fetch it when the instance is starting.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! What would be the alternatives to "plain spawning"? Could you elaborate that or do you have a keyword I can look up?

Comment: Hello, that depends on your application needs. If in your case manually spawning is enough, then above will work just fine. but maybe you would like to make that process a bit more seamless and automatic - that's where you can take a look at Auto Scaling Groups (or ASGs for short), which will automatically spawn new instances based on various metrics (CPU load, network, number of requests) or on time-based schedule.

Comment: Great keywords! Thanks a lot!